# Simulating a mousehover effect on a fontIcon in uwp

Tags: win-universal-app, hamburger-menu

Am currently working on a uwp project involving the use of a hamburger menu. So far I generated the menu using this code

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;"
                      Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,8,0">
```

What I really what to achieve is that when the mouse hovers on the icon, the background colour of the hamburger menu is expected to change. This is similar to a minimize button in a windows app. After searching the API I realised that there wasn't any mousehover event and I think the closest thing to it was a  PointerEnetered event. How do I achieve this with the PointerEntered event in XAML?

Comment: Check this Hamburger menu [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InVsajohErQ) might me it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the solution that has been posted by @Archana to change the foreground color of the FontIcon, for changing the hamburger menu’s background color and let it to be similar to a minimize button in a windows app, we can try to add the FontIcon xaml into the Button’s content and change the Button’s background color to let it look like that we have changed the hamburger menu’s background color.

For handling the mousehover event, as you have said we need to use the [PointerEnetered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.PointerEntered);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true) event. 
But please do not forget to handle the [PointerExited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.PointerExited);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true) event to let the hamburger menu’s background color come back to normal after we do not move the mouse over the hamburger menu .

For more information, please check my sample:

XAML code:

```
 <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="auto">
                    <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" PointerEntered="Button_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Button_PointerExited">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;"
                  Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,8,0"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                 //add other icon
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>
```

CS code:

```
private void Button_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button test = sender as Button;
        test.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    private void Button_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button test = sender as Button;
       test.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    }
```

**If you only want to implement it by using XAML**, please right click the Button to edit the Button style and change the background color of the Button inside the **PointerOver** VisualState as following:

```
 <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
             <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                          </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

For the completed XAML code, please check:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="auto">
                    <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" PointerEntered="Button_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Button_PointerExited">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;"
                  Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,8,0"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                 //add other icon
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The result:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
You cant do that in XAMl. If you want to do in XAMl Use button instead and edit Visual state of Button

```
 <Button Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;" 
     VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,8,0"/>
            </Button>

 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

You can do like this

```
     <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE700;" PointerPressed="FontIcon_PointerPressed" PointerEntered="FontIcon_PointerEntered"
    PointerExited="FontIcon_PointerExited"    Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,8,0"/>

   private void FontIcon_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as FontIcon).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }

        private void FontIcon_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as FontIcon).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }

        private void FontIcon_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as FontIcon).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }
```