# Implementing TeachingTip control for a UWP App

Tags: xaml, uwp, nuget, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

To install the [**TeachingTip**](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/teaching-tip)-control in my UWP app, I've done the following stepts:

1. installed `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` package via Nuget in my project
2. Added `<XamlControlsResources xmlns = "using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />` into `App.xaml`.
3. Imported Namespace `xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"`

I implemented the **TeachingTip**-control as follows:

```
<Button x:Name="BackButton"
        Background="{x:Null}"
        Content="Back"
        Click="BackButton_Click">
    <Button.Resources>
        <controls:TeachingTip x:Name="ToggleThemeTeachingTip"
                              Target="{x:Bind BackButton}"
                              Title="Change themes without hassle"
                              Subtitle="It's easier than ever to see control samples in both light and dark theme!"
                              CloseButtonContent="Got it!">
        </controls:TeachingTip>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>

<Button x:Name="TeachingTipButton"
        Click="TeachingTipButton_OnClick">
</Button>


private void TeachingTipButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleThemeTeachingTip.IsOpen = true;
}
```

When I call the function I get the following `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` error (probably UI error), which I do not understand:

[image]

What could be the problem? Why does not my code work?

**Edit:**
I have now determined that the error is due to `App.xaml`. After I've installed the Nuget package `Microsoft.UI.Xaml`, it's expected to add the following code in `App.xaml`:
[image]

But I have already in `App.xaml` other settings and resources:
[image]

When I try to add only the line in `App.xaml` a key error occurs:

```
<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>
```

If I give the resource entry a key like this:

```
<XamlControlsResources x: Key = "XamlControlsResources" xmlns = "using: Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
```

It comes to a completely different error:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: "The text for this error is not found.

Can not find a Resource with the Name / Key TeachingTipBackgroundBrush
```

How can I properly add the resource `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>` correctly in my App.xaml?

Comment: Can you provide a repo or code with an example of your problem?

Comment: @visc, please see my Edit.

Comment: What's project's target and min version? And OS build version?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT, Windows 10, version 1809 (10.0; Build 17763)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App.xaml file needs to look like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Other styles here -->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
          ...
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into my project and it worked. However, the code you provided above doesn't have Content for the triggering button, so the only button which appears is the top button. Are you sure you're not failing because of code in `BackButton_Click` rather than `TeachingTipButton_OnClick`?

You can remove the duplicate reference to `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` from `Application.Resources`

Comment: It is not due to the function failure. The button events work well and I have no duplicates in app.xaml. I think I have a syntax error in my app.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing *ContentDialog Size style* and *Default Button style* so that `<Application.Resources>` has only `<XamlControlsResources x: Key = "XamlControlsResources" xmlns = "using: Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />` as a single entry. In my case, multiple entries in `<Application.Resources> </Application.Resources>` are unfortunately not accepted.